# Not getting identity field on heap analytics portal for release build

Tags: android

In my Android app , I have implemented Heap Analytics. It is getting records of every click and showing it on Heap Analytics portal. But using Heap.identify() is not displaying identity field on Heap portal.

I have updated plugin and build gradle according to requirements. I have also implemented gradle file changes provided on Heap installation guide.

Lines used for Heap Analytics:

Heap.init(getApplicationContext(),env_id);
Heap.identify(mail_id);

Desired Result:
I want that when Heap.identify is called it will add identity tag with mail id on heap portal.